# Why is JsonConverter attribute not inherited from interface?

Tags: c#, serialization, system.text.json, jsonconvert, jsonconverter

In have the following code:

```
interface ITyped<TypeEnum> where TypeEnum : Enum, struct
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public TypeEnum Type { get; }
}

class Foo : ITyped<FooType>
{
    public Foo(FooType type) { Type = type; }

    public FooType Type { get; init; }
}

enum FooType { type1, type2 }
```

If I serialize a `Foo` instance with `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`, I get an `int` for the `Type` property - although I have specified a `JsonStringEnumConverter` for the `Type` property in the `interface`.

```
var foo = new Foo(FooType.type1);
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo);
    // contains {"Type":0} but I want {"Type":"type1"}
```

It does work if I attach the `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]` to the `Type` property of `Foo` instead.

**But why does it not work if it is attached to the `Type` property of the `interface`?**

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute?view=net-6.0) say that `JsonConverterAttribute` can be put on `System.AttributeTargets.Property`, and since it derives from `Attribute`, it is also `Inherited=true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part is that classes implement interfaces, they don't inherit them.

I see the following options:

- Use a base class
- Use JsonStringEnumConverter "globally" instead of decorating individual members:

  ```
  var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
  options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
  JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo);
  ```